# Python poster buffer size

Tags: python, file-upload, poster

I'm using [Python poster module 0.8.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/poster/) and I was wondering if it possible to increase default  upload buffer size or 'blocksize' ? I found that default buffer size is 4096 bytes ( http://atlee.ca/software/poster/poster.encode.html#poster.encode.MultipartParam.iter_encode )
I tried to search some hints in documentation but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API does not give you the opportunity to set the blocksize, no.

You can increase the buffer by patching the constant on the function:

```
from poster.encode import MultipartParam

iter_encode = MultipartParam.iter_encode.im_func  # function object
iter_encode.func_defaults = (8192,)  # set new defaults, a 1-element tuple
```

The `.func_defaults` parameter of functions can be replaced at will, just make sure you replace it with a tuple of equal length.